# C# Mail Sending Error in smtp.office365.com SMTP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, office365

I am using below Code for SMTP Configuration.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = data.SMTPServer, // smtp server address here...
    Port = data.PortNo,
    EnableSsl = data.SSL,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
    Timeout = 30000,
};
smtp.Send(message);
```

One client has configured SMTP Server - smtp.office365.com.

SMTP Server throws back below Error - Without SSL :-

```
Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [XXX.XXX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

With SSL :-

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [XXXX.XXXX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

Above SMTP Code works perfectly for rest of Clients.
Any inputs what needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Does this resolved for you ? I am facing same issue. if you solved, can you please update here ?

Comment: @SanketPatel Not yet identified. My code is still the same. This issue looks more from the SMTP Server end.

Comment: @Anup Joest's answer worked for me. Make sure you also have EnableSsL set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the points below are correct:

- credentials are correct
- use the right port number (587 or 25)
- application must be able to use TLS 1.2 or higher ( you can test this by adding the following code before calling the service: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`)

Comment: A combination of SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 and EnableSSL = true is what worked for us.